# Pushing to Heroku and get the "remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)" error

Tags: node.js

I have my part of the log below (characters limitation).  Can anyone tell me way to fix this?  Try to push to heroku but got the pre-receive hook declined error.  Interestingly, about a month or two ago, i push the same code without any issue.  But today, no matter what do i, i still get his error.

------------- log --------------

```
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport_op_string.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/trace.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure/server_secure_chttp2.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/bin_decoder.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/bin_encoder.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_plugin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/flow_control.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_data.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_goaway.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_ping.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_rst_stream.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_settings.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_window_update.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_encoder.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_table.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/http2_settings.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/huffsyms.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/incoming_metadata.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/stream_lists.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/stream_map.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/varint.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/writing.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/alpn/alpn.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/client/http_client_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/http_filters_plugin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/message_compress/message_compress_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/server/http_server_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/httpcli_security_connector.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/composite/composite_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials_metadata.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/fake/fake_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/credentials_generic.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/google_default_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/iam/iam_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/json_token.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/jwt_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/jwt_verifier.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/oauth2/oauth2_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/ssl/ssl_credentials.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/client_auth_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/lb_targets_info.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/server_auth_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/tsi_error.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/util/json_util.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init_secure.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts_transport_security.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/fake_transport_security.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security_grpc.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security_adapter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure/secure_channel_create.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/backup_poller.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_factory.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_plugin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/connector.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_connect_handshaker.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_proxy.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy_factory.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy_registry.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/parse_address.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper_registry.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_registry.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/retry_throttle.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel_index.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/uri_parser.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/chttp2_connector.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_plugin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_transport.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/client_load_reporting_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_channel_secure.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_client_stats.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o
     CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/proto/grpc/lb/v1/load_balancer.pb.o
     CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_common.o
     CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_decode.o
     CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_encode.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/fake/fake_resolver.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_robin/round_robin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper_fallback.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/sockaddr/sockaddr_resolver.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/load_reporting/server_load_reporting_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/load_reporting/server_load_reporting_plugin.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/census/grpc_context.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/max_age/max_age_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/message_size/message_size_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_cronet_compression_filter.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds/workaround_utils.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/plugin_registry/grpc_plugin_registry.o
     AR(target) Release/obj.target/libgrpc.a
     COPY Release/libgrpc.a
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/arena.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/atm.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_iphone.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_linux.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_linux.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/env_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/fork.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/host_port.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_android.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/mpscq.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/murmur_hash.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_util_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/string_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/thd.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/thd_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/thd_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_precise.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/time_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tls_pthread.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_msys.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_posix.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_windows.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/wrap_memcpy.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/profiling/basic_timers.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/gpr/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/profiling/stap_timers.o
     AR(target) Release/obj.target/libgpr.a
     COPY Release/libgpr.a
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o
   In file included from ../../../../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:203,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::Function>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Function>::New(Nan::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:105:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Function::New(v8::Isolate*&, void (&)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Object>&)’
                              , obj));
                                   ^
   In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:51,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:4170:31: note: candidate: static v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::Function::New(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType)
      static MaybeLocal<Function> New(
                                  ^~~
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:4170:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘v8::Isolate*’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Context>’
   In file included from ../../../../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:203,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::StringObject>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::StringObject>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::StringObject::New(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
      return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                        ^
   In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:51,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5426:23: note: candidate: static v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::StringObject::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>)
      static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
                          ^~~
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:5426:23: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   In file included from ../../../../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:203,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
      return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                             ^
   ../../../../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
      return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                               ^
   In file included from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:0:
   ../../../../../nan/nan.h: In constructor ‘Nan::Utf8String::Utf8String(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
   ../../../../../nan/nan.h:1034:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToString()’
          v8::Local<v8::String> string = from->ToString();
                                                        ^
   In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:51,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2572:44: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
      V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                               ^~~~~~~~
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2572:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
   In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
                    from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:25,
                    from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:51,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2588:31: note: candidate: v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Isolate*) const
                    Local<String> ToString(Isolate* isolate) const);
                                  ^
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
      declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
      ^~~~~~~~~~
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2588:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
                    Local<String> ToString(Isolate* isolate) const);
                                  ^
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
      declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
      ^~~~~~~~~~
   In file included from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:0:
   ../../../../../nan/nan.h:1044:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*&, int, int, const int&)’
            length_ = string->WriteUtf8(str_, static_cast<int>(len), 0, flags);
                                                                             ^
   In file included from /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                    from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:51,
                    from ../ext/byte_buffer.cc:21:
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2782:7: note: candidate: int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char*, int, int*, int) const
      int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
          ^~~~~~~~~
   /app/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0/include/node/v8.h:2782:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘v8::Isolate*’
   grpc_node.target.mk:177: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o' failed
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o] Error 1
   make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/build'
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
   gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
   Failed to execute '/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_64133d0a6490067cb004ed1b1b8c3fde/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! grpc@1.11.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.11.3 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.vIx57/_logs/2019-11-07T15_05_57_490Z-debug.log
```

-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   Some possible problems:

   - node_modules checked into source control
     https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
```

Comment: Do you still have a package.json file in the directory you're pushing to Heroku?  If not Heroku won't recognize it as a Node app and will reject.  That could be one solution.

Comment: yes. I still have my package.json.    Interestingly, the same directory holding the exact same file was pushed about 2 months ago without any issue.  nothing was changed and I push it today to a new app.  This happened.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a newer version of the `grpc` library.

That log shows that you are installing `grpc` version 1.11.3 on Node 12. The latest version of `grpc` is 1.24.2, and in between there have been fixes to make the library work on newer versions of Node, including Node 12.